# In what cases is $\gcd(a,2b) = 2\gcd(a,b)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I know that $\gcd(a,2b) = 2\gcd(a,b)$ is false, counter examples abound.

I am hoping for some pointers to help get a related statement that is provable, that is, conditions on $a$ and $b$ such that :

$$
\gcd(a,2b) = 2\gcd(a,b)
$$

For instance, I know that if the $\gcd(a,2b) = 1$, then this is always false.

Or actually, that the $\gcd(a,2b)$ must be even, and in fact $a$ must be even.

Comment: $gcd(5,2\times3)=1\neq 2 \times gcd(5,3)=2$

Comment: Hint:  it is true when $ord_2(a)>ord_2(b)$, not otherwise.

Comment: multiplying $b$ with some prime factor  $p$ will only affect $\gcd(a,b)$ if $p$ is also a factor of $a$.

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$\gcd(a,2b) = 2\gcd(a,b) \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \nu_2(a)>\nu_2(b)$$

because

$$\gcd(a,b) = 2^{\min(\nu_2(a),\nu_2(b))} \gcd(a',b')$$

where $a'=a/2^{\nu_2(a)}$ and $b'=b/2^{\nu_2(b)}$.

Comment: Fixed a small typo. Note that $\nu_p (n)$ denotes the power of $p$ in the prime factorisation of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all so much!

So if I understand this correctly, $gcd(a,2b) = 2gcd(a,b)$ as long as $a$ has more factors of $2$ than $b$.

It seems so simple now!

Comment: Conversely, $\gcd(a,2b) = \gcd(a,b)$ whenever the above condition does not hold.